# How to use ifelse with dates

Tags: r, date, if-statement, multiple-columns, categories

I have dates in R in format 01/01/2000

I want to create a column with a category that categorizes my subjects as date of birth before the `01/02/2001 ==1`  or after `02/02/2001 ==2`. Would this be done with an `ifelse`?

How would you express this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to extract the day in each date?

Comment: I want to have a column df$date_category with two factors (1== before and 2== after) in which I categorise the dates from the column df$date using a cutoff of 01/02/2001, so dates before first february 2001 get a 1 and those after get a 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 : `ifelse()`**

```
ifelse(as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y") < as.Date("2001-02-02"), 1, 2)
# [1] 1 2 2 2
```

**Option 2**

```
2 - (as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y") < as.Date("2001-02-02"))
# [1] 1 2 2 2
```

**Option 3 : `findInterval()`**

```
findInterval(as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), as.Date("2001-02-02")) + 1
# [1] 1 2 2 2
```

---

**Data**

```
date <- c("01/02/2001", "02/02/2001", "03/02/2001", "04/02/2001")
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends of the formats and you have to add the function "as.Date()

for example :

> dates <- c("01-02-2001", "30-01-2001", "15-05-2001", "08-10-1992","08-09-2020")

> adates=as.Date(dates, "%d-%m-%Y")
>
> ifelse(adates>as.Date("01-02-2001","%d-%m-%Y"),1,0)